# 3D lookup table to discretize the volume

Tags: c++, kinect, depth, lookup-tables, large-data-volumes

I have a depth camera that returns measured distance values of the volume in millimeters. It's needed to create a 3D lookup table to store all possible distance values for each pixel in the image. So I am getting an array of the size 640x480x2048. This approach is very memory consuming and if I use integers in C++ it takes about 2.5 GB of RAM. Additionally, I also have some parameters for each item in the volume, so all together it reaches maximum capacity of my 4GB memory.

My question is: Is there any good experience how I can optimally store and manage above described data set?

P.S Please don't consider the option of file storage. It doesn't fit me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the table dense or sparse? If `table[x][y][depth]` is set for every possible `(x, y, depth)`, then there is no way to optimize it and you just need more RAM. But if, for example, only a couple of the `depth` entries are set at each (x, y), then you could optimize it by using a `map` for each pixel value.

Comment: Well, I did not store the depth when I was doing look up tables, but either way, but you could use RLE if certain adjacent points had the same depth.